What does it mean when an SSD works slow?
I have a SSD Sata 512GB.
2 days ago it starts to work very slow.
When I check SSD parameters with Crystal Disk info and everything is okay.

I've changed the SATA cable, and also I've changed SATA port, but is the same situation.
I've tried to reformat and reinstall everything. Even during setup he works very very slow.
And after installation, it is very slow.
I've tested the SSD on another PC, and it is the same situation.
What does it mean? Because as I've said SSD parameters are okay.

check SSd parameters with Crystal Disk info which parameters did you check?

@JaromandaX i've checked and all parameters a re GOOD , health status is 100%.

How did I know you were going to say that - what brand, model and size is the drive? how old is the drive? what's the max TBW of the drive? How much data has been written in its life?
